# How to check whether inputs are words, space and newLine?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, keyboard-events

```js
let msgInpt = document.getElementById("message");
msgInpt.addEventListener("keydown", function(entEvt){
    if (!msgInpt.innerText === ' ') {
        if (entEvt.code === 'Enter' && !entEvt.shiftKey) {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            postChat();
        }
    } else {
        if (entEvt.code === 'Enter' && !entEvt.shiftKey) {
           entEvt.preventDefault();
           return false;
        } else if(entEvt.code === 'Enter' && entEvt.shiftKey) {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else if (entEvt.code === 'Space') {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #f2f2f4;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="message"></div>
```

**After that I tried this**

```
msgInpt.addEventListener("keydown", function(entEvt){
    if (msgInpt.innerText) {
        if (entEvt.code === 'Enter' && !entEvt.shiftKey) {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            if (!msgInpt.innerText === ' ') {
                postChat();
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (entEvt.code === 'Enter' && !entEvt.shiftKey) {
           entEvt.preventDefault();
           return false;
        } else if(entEvt.code === 'Enter' && entEvt.shiftKey) {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else if (entEvt.code === 'Space') {
            entEvt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to validate whether the user is giving input as word only.
When user **First** gives input of   or `\n` only, then user must not be able to send messages.

Why Both the codes are not working?

Please can anybody tell me what is the logic behind this

Comment: can you provide a sample input?

Comment: Yes I can provide

Comment: why use `!msgInpt.innerText === ' '`, instead of `msgInpt.innerText.trim() !== ''`

Comment: I think you should check the message text itself instead of the key events.

Comment: @Iupz I already cross checked it! and it is solved now!

Answer (score -1):

You can always use Regular Expression for this kind of query. It helps you to overcome the space and newline input problem easily.

Refer this article for using RegEx in javascript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Maybe add an example or refer to another SO response.